# I can't import tkinter in pycharm community edition

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I've been trying for a few days now, to be able to import the library tkinter in pycharm. But, I am unable to do so.
,I tried to import it or to install some packages but still nothing, I reinstalled python and pycharm again nothing. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I am using pycharm community edition 2018 2.3 and python 3.7 .

EDIT:So , I uninstalled python 3.7 and I installed python 3.6 x64 ,I tried changing my interpreter to the new path to python and still not working...

EDIT 2 : I installed pycharm pro(free trial 30 days) and it's actually works and I tried to open my project in pycharm community and it's not working...

EDIT 3 : I installed python 3.6 x64 and now it's working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you do `pip list` on the command prompt of your choice, does it have tkinter in the list? CMD also Alt+F12 on PyCharm.

Comment: Have chosen the correct internetet where you have installed the tkinter module

Comment: I don't have tkinter in the list.

Comment: As we discussed in my now deleted answer (should've been here.. sorry), tkinter ships with Python and works in your IDLE. I sadly don't have any information specifically about PyCharm in this situation. All I can say is that it works for me also in PyCharm. I have Python 3.6.0 x64.

Comment: I think I'm gonna install Python 3.6 too and see if it's work.

Comment: If youd "don't have tkinter in the list", you probably should install it. `pip3 install tkinter`. Remember that you have to install it in the venv that PyCharm is using for your project. And remember in py3 you have to import tkinter with all lowercase letters. `import tkinter`.

Comment: sorry auto complete changed my comment, i meant to say, have you chosen the right python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vsDeus for asking this question. I had the same problem running Linux Mint Mate 19.1 and nothing got tkinter and some other modules working in Pycharm CE. In Eclipse with Pydev all worked just fine but for some reason I would rather work in Pycharm when coding than Eclipse.

The steps outlined here did not work for me but the steps he took handed me the solution. Basically I had to uninstall Pycharm, remove all its configuration files, then reinstall pip3, tkinter and then reinstall Pycharm CE. Finally I reopened previously saved projects and then set the correct interpreter.

When I tried to change the python interpreter before no alternatives appeared. After all these steps the choice became available. Most importantly now tkinter, matplotlib and other modules I wanted to use are available in Pycharm.